# Javascript Syntax Highlight not working in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse

All my javascript files are greyed out in Eclipse (2022-09).

I have Wild Web Developer installed and have followed other threads advice of changing the file association of ".js" to "generic text editor" however none of these solutions work for me.

Would appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: For me it works without problems. Please edit your question and add a JavaScript example file as text and a screenshot of what you see.

Comment: You shouldn't have *had* to change a file association. Are you sure you're opening your file in the Generic Text Editor? This is a file inside a project in the workspace, right?

Comment: I have the same problem. It was working with 2020-12, but now with 2022-09 syntax highlighting in .js files is missing. I'm still using "Generic Text Editor" to view them. They are inside Eclipse (Gradle) projects.